# Scala + Lift + MongoDB = NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: scala, noclassdeffounderror

I'm new in Scala and Lift. Trying to create simple rest service.

this is mine User object:

```
object User extends MongoDocumentMeta[User]{
  override def collectionName = "users"
  override def formats = super.formats + new ObjectIdSerializer + new DateSerializer
}

case class User(_id: ObjectId, login: String, email: String, password: String, created: Date) extends MongoDocument[User] {
  def meta = User
}
```

and this is a rest service:

```
object users extends RestHelper {
  serve {
    case "users" :: Nil JsonGet _ => Extraction.decompose(User.findAll)
    case "users" :: userId :: Nil JsonGet _ => Extraction.decompose(User.find(userId))
  }
}
```

on `GET http://localhost:8080/users` request it returns

Problem accessing /users. Reason:

```
scala/reflect/Manifest$
```

Caused by:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/Manifest$
>       at net.liftweb.mongodb.JObjectParser$$anon$1.(JObjectParser.scala:39)
>       at net.liftweb.mongodb.JObjectParser$.(JObjectParser.scala:39)
>       at net.liftweb.mongodb.JObjectParser$.(JObjectParser.scala)
>       at net.liftweb.mongodb.MongoDocumentMeta$class.create(MongoDocument.scala:55)
>       at code.model.User$.create(User.scala:16)
>       at net.liftweb.mongodb.MongoDocumentMeta$$anonfun$findAll$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MongoDocument.scala:111)
>       at net.liftweb.mongodb.MongoDocumentMeta$$anonfun$findAll$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MongoDocument.scala:111)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1156)
>
> ...

where I made a mistake?

Comment: What version of Scala are you using? Also, what are you using for dependency management: SBT, Maven, something else? If might help if you could post your dependency listing? You might be depending on a library that was compiled against a different version of Scala than the one you are currently using.

Comment: Scala - 2.10.0. 

Lift - 2.6-M1.

SBT. 

"net.liftweb" % "lift-mongodb_2.9.1" % "2.5"

Comment: @Gengzu major scala versions are binary incompatible, take [lift compiled against 2.10.x](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.liftweb/lift-mongodb_2.10) otherwise downgrade your scala to either 2.9.1 , 2.9.2, 2.9.3